# R - skipping of commands in function

Tags: r, function, return

When I have data matrices

```
mI <- c(1:4, 2, 6, 9)
mJ <- c(4:1, 5, 0, 2)
```

and the following simple regression function

```
fLM <- function(mX, mY){
       lmXY <- lm(mY~mX)
       summary(lmXY)
       return(lmXY)
}
```

It is obvious that I want to print the outcomes of the regression in the function by using the command summary(lmXY). But using LM <- fLM(mI, mJ) the summary output is not printed, even though this command is included in the function. Strangely (for me at least) summary(lmXY) is printed when I remove the return(lmXY) command in function fLM. Can someone explain why this happens?

Something similar occurs when I establish a Bloomberg connection in a function using

```
conn <- blpConnect()
```

A couple of commands later in the function I use blpDisconnect(conn) to disconnect from Bloomberg. The next command returns the retreived data. But while blpConnect() works perfectly, the blpDisconnect(conn) command is skipped. The return of the data is executed perfectly. When I manually establish a connection with Bloomberg and then use the disconnect function there is no problem. But somehow in functions which include return (I am not sure whether this is the cause though, it is merely an observation) there is a problem. Does anybody knows why?

Global code of BB function:

```
fnBB <- function(){
        conn <- blpConnect()
        ...
        blpDisconnect(conn)
        return(mData)
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: I think of this along the lines of how a function can only return one object. The output of `summary` is something which you're trying to return to the parent environment which gets overridden by the `return`. If you `cat(summary, file = "somefile")`, you will see that the content is captured in that file (albeit with formatting issues). I don't know the actual reason why this happens though, hence a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Objects don't get printed in a function unless:

1. You explicitly tell the function to print it.
2. That object is what is returned by the function.

You should run `print(summary(lmXY))` instead.

```
f1 <- function() {1 ; 2}
f2 <- function() {print(1) ; 2}
f3 <- function() {print(1) ; return(2)} # identical to f2

f1() #prints 2
object = f1() #stores 2, prints nothing
object = f2() #stores 2, prints 1
f2() #prints 1 and 2
```

Comment: ninja'd by the good SenorO !.  Lucky for you my name isn't Inigo Montoya :-)

Comment: I will prepare to die, just to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

If you type a command at the regular prompt and the command does not assign the output somewhere then R will call `print` on the value returned.  But inside of a function or loop this automatic printing does not happen (see FAQ 7.16).  So if you want the summary information printed then just call the `print` function.

Note that the `summary` functions do not generally print anything, they return a summary object that is printed by a `print.summary` function.  When you remove the `return` statement then the `summary` call is the last thing in the function, so the return value (the summary object) is what is returned from the function.  If you call the function without assigning the result to anything then the autoprinting kicks in.  With the return statement, the lmXY object is being returned, so that is what would be printed (but will not print if it is set as invisible).